# connect backend server to client for stripe checkout

Tags: reactjs, api, stripe-payments, backend

trying to add my backend server which is deployed on render.com which needs to be called to access stripe payment however im having difficulty in doing this as im new to backend could someone please help

server

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World, from express");
});

app.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
  const items = req.body.items;
  let lineItems = [];
  items.forEach((item) => {
    lineItems.push({
      price: item.id,
      quantity: item.quantity,
    });
  });
```

client

```
const checkout = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch("http://localhost:4000/checkout", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ items: cart.items }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.url) {
          window.location.assign(response.url); // Forwarding user to Stripe
        }
      });
  };
```

i changed the localhost:4000/checkout to my server url however i keep getting a 404 when i do this

tried changing the fetch address to my render deployed url received a 404